# Generating digits from 0 to 9 (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I was reading a source code of a program for solving algebrogram. A part of it is a procedure which tries out every digit from 0 to 9. This is the source code for it:

```
digit(0, 0) :- !.
digit(X, X).
digit(D, N) :-
  N2 is N - 1 ,
  digit(D, N2) .
```

When I run this and ask I get:

```
?- digit(X, 9).
X = 9 ;
X = 8 ;
X = 7 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 0.
```

I don't quite seem to understand why the procedure *digit* does this. Could somebody explain this to me?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, some terminology. `digit` is referred to in Prolog as a "predicate", not a "procedure" or a "function". What makes this important is that a "predicate" doesn't do exactly what a function or procedure does. A predicate is a description of a logical relation, and calling a predicate makes an attempt to satisfy a logical goal defined by that relation, for which there may be zero, one, or many solutions. To satisfy the goal, it can instantiate any uninstantiated variables or terms (those that have not yet been assigned a value).

To understand the behavior of `digit`, you want to "read" through it with the understanding of what a predicate does. The meaning of `digit(X, N)` in this context is that "X is a digit in the range 0 to N". If `N` is 0, then we would expect only one answer (0) for `X` by that definition. If `N > 0` then we'd expect that there are multiple answers which will make `digit(X, N)` true. The rules (predicates) written for this are:

```
digit(0, 0) :- !.
digit(X, X).
digit(X, N) :- N2 is N - 1, digit(X, N2).
```

The ordering here is important because Prolog will attempt to match these rules in the order given, as described below.

The first declared fact is:

```
digit(0, 0) :- !.
```

This says that 0 is the *only* digit between 0 and 0. I say *only* because the cut will tell Prolog not to look for any more answers after satisfying this goal. So `digit(0, 0)` will be true, and the goal `digit(X, 0).` would produce `X = 0` and be done.

Next there's:

```
digit(X, X).
```

This states that `X` is a valid digit from 0 to `X`. There's no cut, so subsequent solutions may be sought after this rule is satisfied. A goal such as `digit(X, 9)` will match this rule, and yield `X = 9`. Note that when you type in `digit(X, 9)`, the first found result is `X = 9` because this is the first rule encountered which satisfies the requested goal of `digit(X, 9)`.

Finally, there's:

```
digit(X, N) :- N2 is N - 1, digit(X, N2).
```

This says that `X` is a digit from 0 to `N` if `X` is a digit from `0` to `N - 1` (`N2` is used to instantiate the value `N-1`). So if I enter a goal `digit(X, 9)`, it first satisfies `digit(X, X)` as described above. Then, since there's no cut in that rule, when Prolog backtracks for more solutions, it has already satisfied `digit(X, X)` so will move on to satisfy `digit(X, 9)` and, in the process, attempt to satisfy `digit(X, 8)` as described by the rule for `digit(X, N)`. Since this is a new goal (not the original `digit(X, 9)` goal), it starts from the top and, by the same logic, will first encounter `digit(X, X)` and by satisfied by `X = 8`. Thus, the second solution displayed will be `X = 8` (remember the first solution given was `X = 9`).

This logic continues in sequence, satisfying `digit(X, 7)`, `digit(X, 6)`, etc, showing solutions of `X = 7`, `X = 6`, etc, accordingly until it finally gets to `digit(X, 0)`. As described above, `digit(X, 0)` will finally be satisfied by `digit(0, 0)`, yielding solution `X = 0` and then be done because of the cut. At this point, it has exhausted all of the solutions and finishes.

So, the result is `X = 9`, `X = 8`, ..., `X = 0`.

The key to this is that Prolog continues (iterating/backtracking) finding solutions to your stated goal, finding all possible solutions, until it finds all of the possibilities (as established by the written rules as predicates), or until these possibilities are truncated using cuts.